# Need help plotting multiple functions

Tags: plotting

a = 0.5

b = 0.33333

r = 1.5

e = -0.33333

f = 1

g = 1

m = 0.00001

n = 0.33334

o = 0.00001

p = 0.000003

DSolve[{
  x'[t] == a*y[t] ,

y'[t] == -b*r*y[t] - x[t] - e - f + g*y[t],

z'[t] == m*(x[t] + n) - o (z[t] + p),

x[0] == 0.001,

y[0] == 0.999,

z[0] == 0}, {x, y, z}, t]

Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]

When I try to plot this, it just stays blank (no error).

Comment: Try searching the site and you will find an exact duplicate (if not thousands) -- it's easily reachable.

Comment: It seems you forgot to put in spaces or asterisks in `-bry[t]`.

Answer (score 2):

The results of the `DSolve` must be used in the `Plot`

```
a = 0.5;
b = 0.33333;
r = 1.5;
e = -0.33333;
f = 1;
g = 1;
m = 0.00001;
n = 0.33334;
o = 0.00001;
p = 0.000003;

sol = DSolve[{
    x'[t] == a*y[t],
    y'[t] == -b*r*y[t] - x[t] - e - f + g*y[t],
    z'[t] == m*(x[t] + n) - o (z[t] + p),
    x[0] == 0.001, y[0] == 0.999, z[0] == 0},
   {x, y, z}, t];

Plot[Evaluate[
  {x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol],
 {t, 0, 75},
 PlotLegends -> {x[t], y[t], z[t]},
 PlotRange -> {-15, 15},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]